# Calculating Haar features

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, math

I am confused on how to solve this problem, does anyone have any ideas?

https://www.merl.com/publications/docs/TR2004-043.pdf

For a [Haar filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_feature) $H \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 5}$ defined as below:

What is the equation to calculate the Haar features using integral image II?

In this problem an input images is $I \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and integral image is denoted by $II\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$

$H = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 &0\\
0 & -1 & -1 & 1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned the Haar filters use a lookup table with the say $A_{i,j} = \sum_{k=0}^{i} \sum_{l=1}^{j} I_{k,l}$

Now consider a the convolution with a filter $H \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, such that $H_{i,j}=1$, the convolution will can be calculated as
$$\begin{eqnarray}Y_{i,j} &=& \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{l=1}^{n} H_{k,l} I_{i-k+1, j-k+1} \\
&=&  \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{l=1}^{n} I_{i-k+1, j-k+1} \\
&=&  \sum_{k=i-m+1}^{i} \sum_{l=j-n+1}^{j} I_{k, l} \\
&=&  \sum_{k=i-m+1}^{i} \left( \sum_{l=0}^{j} I_{k, l} -  \sum_{l=0}^{j-n} I_{k, l}\right) \\
&=&  \sum_{k=0}^{i} \left( \sum_{l=0}^{j} I_{k, l} -  \sum_{l=0}^{j-n} I_{k, l}\right) - \sum_{k=0}^{i-m+1} \left( \sum_{l=0}^{j} I_{k, l} -  \sum_{l=0}^{j-n} I_{k, l}\right)\\
&=&  \left(A_{i,j} -  A_{i,j-n}\right) - \left( A_{i-m,j} -  A_{i-m, j-n}\right)\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Of course you can generalize this for $H_{i,j} = c$ for constant $c$ (by multiplying the resulting image), and you can use the shifting properties of the convolution if the filter is padded.

Now looking to your $H$, it can be decomposed in two rectangular regions constant regions. It can be decomposed as

$$H_1 + H_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} + (-1) \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

To convolve with a the non-zero submatrix of $H_1$, a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}$ you will use $A_{i,j} + A_{i-3, j-1} - A_{i, j-1} - A_{i-3,j}$

To convolve with the non-zero submatrix of $H_2$, a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 2}$ you will use $A_{i,j} + A_{i-3, j-2} - A_{i, j-2} - A_{i-3,j}$

Of course you can have other conventions for the indices...